# Determine if an undirected graph is bipartite in Java

Tags: java, graph

I am asked to determine if a graph is bipartite. A bipartite graph is one in which the nodes can be divided into two groups such that no nodes have direct edges to other nodes in the same group. The assumption is:

> The graph is represented by a list of nodes, and the list of nodes is not null.

And the GraphNode class is given as follow:

```
    /**
 * public class GraphNode {
 *   public int key;
 *   public List<GraphNode> neighbors;
 *   public GraphNode(int key) {
 *     this.key = key;
 *     this.neighbors = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();
 *   }
 * }
 */
```

My attempt is as follow:

```
public class Solution{
    public boolean isBipartite(List<GraphNode> graph){

        HashSet<GraphNode> store = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<GraphNode> compare = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<GraphNode> iterate = new HashSet<>();
        Queue<GraphNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        GraphNode cur = graph.get(0);
        queue.offer(cur);
        boolean answer = true;

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            cur = queue.poll();

            List<GraphNode> list = cur.neighbors;

            int i = 0;
            while (i<list.size()){
                GraphNode node = list.get(i);
                if (compare.contains(node)){
                    answer = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (!store.contains(node)){
                    queue.offer(node);
                    iterate.add(node);
                    store.add(node);
                }
            }

            if (answer == false) {
                break;
            }

            store.add(cur);
            compare.clear();
            Iterator<GraphNode> temp = iterate.iterator();
            while (temp.hasNext()){
                compare.add(temp.next());
            }
        }

        return answer; //it’s always harder to verify true than false.
    }
}
```

So the idea is to use `store` to keep records of all the **expanded graph node**, so the expanded node won't be expanded again. Also, I want the `compare` HashSet to store the expanded nodes from the previous round because in bipartite, a node should not be generated in consecutive order. Whenever the node is generated in consecutive order, the loop will be broken and the program should return false. Also, the `compare` set will be cleared at every round and the generated node at the last round be filled into this set.

I think my logic should be correct but the program seems not working... currently it reports me with

> Timed out, possible infinite loop or too much recursion

Can someone please help me by identifying loop in my code or if my logic is wrong?

Comment: This part: `int i = 0;      while (i<list.size()){` You never increment `i`, so that condition is permanently true

Comment: @Michael ahhh, yes. I changed that but the answer is still wrong...

Comment: @Michael when the input is {0->1;1->0;2->3,4;3->2,4;4->2,3}

Comment: It looks like this is a leetcode (or similar) problem, right? Part of the trouble with solving problems there is that you can't step through your solution with a debugger. I'd try to copy your solution over to an IDE, which will mean that you'll have to construct some test inputs yourself because AFAIK leetcode don't give you code for the test cases. That will allow you to step through line by and line and see if it does what you expect.